# How to find distinct values across multiple columns in excel?

Tags: excel, unique, distinct

So lets say I have two columns on two different tabs.

**tab1**

```
col1      
apple       
banana  
grape     
strawberry
strewberry
```

**tab2**

```
col2
grape
berry
orange
strawberri
grape
```

All I would like to do is automatically have a column three which is simply an alphabetized list of unique values in both columns

**Final Output**

```
col3
apple       
banana  
berry
grape   
orange 
strawberri 
strawberry
strewberry
```

Comment: What version of Excel are you working with? Does it support `UNIQUE`, `SORT`, etc.?

Comment: unsure on version but yes! I have these functions

Comment: Do you have TOCOL and or VSTACK also?

Comment: Negatory on TOCOL and VSTACK @ScottCraner

Comment: @BigBen VERSION 2202

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on most Microsoft-365 with most recent release then try-

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(VSTACK(TOCOL(Sheet1!A:A,1),TOCOL(Sheet2!A:A,1))))
```

Otherwise go with `FILTERXML()` and `TEXTJOIN()`.

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!A:A)&"</s></t>","//s")))
```

[image]

Comment: Sadly Im on Version 2202 Build 14931.20660

Comment: Lets try `FILTERXML()` with `TEXTJOIN()`. See edited answer.